# Typescript TS2604: JSX element type 'Drawer' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have tried others solution finded in stackoverflow, but myabe i mistake something, because anyone not work for me.

someone can help to correct this ts error ?

**Error TS2604: JSX element type 'Drawer' does not have any construct or call signatures.**

all tests fail

with function

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core";
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';
const DrawerB = () => (

            <Drawer
                open={true}
            >
                <h1>AAAA</h1>
            </Drawer>
        );
```

with Class

```
        class DrawerA extends Component<any, any>{
            constructor(props){
                super(props)
            }
            render(){
                return (
                    <Drawer
                        open={true}
                    >
                        <h1>AAAA</h1>
                    </Drawer>
                )
            }
        }
```

with class and without construct

```
        class DrawerC extends Component<any, any>{

            render(){
                return (
                    <Drawer
                        open={true}
                    >
                        <h1>AAAA</h1>
                    </Drawer>
                )
            }
        }
```

Comment: What you want to do? and can you create demo in stakcblitz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your import as follows may help you:

```
import { Drawer } from "@material-ui/core";
```